# CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString) says CloudStorageAccount.cs not found

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-.net

In my WebAPI controller I am trying to post to my Azure Blob Storage. I am trying to connect in the following manner:

```
string blobConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorageAccount"].ConnectionString;
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("testContainer");
```

However just doing this returns a 500 and walking through this line by line in the debugger after

> CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString)

it returns a Source Not Found error in Visual Studio where it says:

> CloudStorageAccount.cs not found, You need to find
>   CloudStorageAccount.cs to view the source for the current call stack
>   frame.

Is this a issue with me missing a file or is this a issue with my connection string? My web config is:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="AzureStorageAccount" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=somecustomname;AccountKey=accesskey" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was me debugging using F11 (Step Into) rather than F10 (Step Over).